# How to run batch file from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, batch-file, iis-7

I have code that I use on a button.

```
string direktoriWorking = Server.MapPath("~/Mapping/jk/");
string fileBatch = "mapping_jk.bat";
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(fileBatch);
processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
processInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", sFileName, createdby);
processInfo.WorkingDirectory = direktoriWorking;
Process batchProcess = new Process();
batchProcess.StartInfo = processInfo;
batchProcess.Start();
```

When I run the application when the debug mode, the program code to run a bat file to run smoothly. However, when I run an application that has been published, when the button is clicked, a bat file does not run. If I run the bat file directly, not an error. 
I've tried to give permissions to IIS_IUSRS, NETWORK SERVICE, and IUSRS bat file to the folder where it is located. But the results are still not able to.

Can you help to find solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your application pool is configured to run using the Application Pool Identity feature then an account called `IIS AppPool\<pool name>` will be created, and it is a machine-level user not domain level user. so basically, go to Application Pools in IIS, check what is the name of the app pool that your asp.net application is running under, and then give permission to it on the required folder / file. if you are using the default Application Pool Identity, the user will be `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool` make sure you search this user with location set as your machine not as your domain.